# Given an array of size 3N make N triplets out of it so as to maximize sum of triplets' median

Tags: algorithm

The problem statement is
Given an array of size 3N unique positive integer elements, find N triplets where
Triplet(i) = (xi,yi,zi) xi < yi < zi

There can be various such combinations. Find the maximum sum of Yi's of triplets that can be achieved.

eg - array - [ 1 3 5 2 4 6]  of size K = 3N
triplets (1, 5, 6) (2, 3, 4) max sum = 8  that can be achieved.

I tried sorting the elements descending and picking (index 1 to index 2N,  alternate items as greedy approach to maximize sum) and it does not give the right answer for many test cases or is it that i am missing an edge case.

K can be approx. 10^6.

my code - rather than descending it does ascending and rather than start with 1 and go to 2N . it goes from k-2 to N.
https://ideone.com/FsB5y9

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
int[] arr = new int[k];
String line = br.readLine();
String[] nums = line.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < k;i++)
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
Arrays.sort(arr);
long total = 0; // use long not int
for(int i = k-2, j = 1; j <= k/3 ; i-= 2, j++) {
    total += arr[i];
   }
System.out.println(total);
}
```

However, for some test cases this failed. I could not identify those test cases and i could not get them as it was an online interview question.

Comment: Can you tell what these test cases are?

Comment: I dont have the test cases. But i do know that my code failed for a few cases on hackerearth test. If i can get a proof whether my algo is false or correct, that will be great.
even i am onto it to prove that this soln. essentially gives the right answer.

Comment: @גלעדברקן i dont see how 2 < 3 < 4 fails ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, thinking the inequality was for indexes rather than values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have found a proof of this algorithm. It might have been some faulty test case or so.

First we sort the array of 3N elements.

```
We don't ever take the first N lowest no.s 

x1,x2,x3,x4.....xN are reserved for first place in any triplet
```

the rest of the no.s can be picked or not picked for the middle candidate as follows.
If I pick this no. then there must be at least one no. greater than this that can be included in the triplet and should not have been used in any other triplet.

Eg. below

```
> Assumption and Constraint:
>     _ means picked O means not picked the element in 2N sized greater part of array
> 
> at any point where _ is present there are at least more Os then _s to
> the right of it. Only then there can such valid formation of triplets
> possible.

         _ _ O O _ _ _ O O _  O  O
 index   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

Now, we know that A[1] < A[2] < A[3] < A[4] < A[5] ....... A[2N]

current sum - A[1] + A[2] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7] + A[10]
```

we can always swap 10 with 11 and still get a bigger total

```
_ _ O O _ _ _ O O O  _  O
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

new sum = A[1] + A[2] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7] + A[11]  (A[11] > A[10])
```

again, if we swap 8 and 7, we will end up with a bigger sum.

```
_ _ O O _ _ O _ O O  _  O
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12


new sum = A[1] + A[2] + A[5] + A[6] + A[8] + A[11]  (A[8] > A[7])
```

Similarly, again we can swap 8, 9 to get the better sum and we get this arrangement

```
_ _ O O _ _ O O _ O  _  O
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

new sum = A[1] + A[2] + A[5] + A[6] + A[9] + A[11]  (A[9] > A[8])
```

Now, we can swap 7 and 6 again

```
  _ _ O O _ O _ O _ O  _  O
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

new sum = A[1] + A[2] + A[5] + A[7] + A[9] + A[11]  (A[7] > A[6])
```

Now, we can still swap 3 and 4 to maintain the constraint of triplet formation
and get a bigger value:

```
_ O _ O _ O _ O _ O  _  O
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

new sum = A[1] + A[3] + A[5] + A[7] + A[9] + A[11]  (A[3] > A[2])
```

Essentially, any continuously non selected elements can be swapped with a lower selected value to get a higher sum while holding the constraint.

Eventually, we will get all alternate elements starting from 1 to 2N-1 for the greater 2N part of the sorted array to get the highest sum of such triplets' median.
We cannot maximize more than this without upholding the constraint of triplets formation.

I hope this works. Still, i dont know why the testcases failed.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array : O(nlogn) .

1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5, 6, 7 ,8 ,9 , 10 ,11 , 12

1st element of triplet from front and 2md and 3rd element of triplet from back

<1 , 11 , 12> , < 2 , 9 , 10 > ,< 3 ,7 ,8 > , < 4 , 5 , 6 >

Answer (score 1):

I followed the answer given by @vikas ray and improved a bit upon it.
Following is the Python 3 code I used to get the most efficient answer:

```
def sumReturn(arr,N):
    '''
    arr: Input array of length 3N
    N: Number of triplets to be found
    '''
    arr.sort()
    sum=0
    for i in range(N):
         sum=sum+arr[-2*(i+1)]
    return(sum)
```

Logic used:
We need to form the triplets using the 1st, 2nd last and last items from the array.

The array also needs to be updated whenever this operation is performed.

For getting the sum of the middle element of each triplet, we are in essence taking only the 2nd last element in each iteration for a total of N iterations.

Deleting the 1st element doesn't change the 2nd last element's position at any moment.

For each iteration, we will be selecting the following items from the end of the array(using pythonic notation):
items -2 and -1
items -4 and -3
items -6 and -5 and so on...

Using the same logic, I found that we only needed to take the multiples of 2 from the end to get the sum a total of N times.

The same logic was used to draft the code.

Please let me know for any queries and I will be happy to answer them.